# How do I do a SUMPRODUCT in Google Sheets, but conditional on the text in both vectors?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

The following spreadsheet shows the exercise submission status for 4 students. There are 4 exercises (1-4), but only 2 of them are homework (and thus graded) - they have a prefix 'H' in their name. A correct submission is marked "complete".

I'm trying to count, for each student, how many "complete" submissions he has, which are also homework. The right-most column is my desired result.

I tried all kinds of countifs, but couldn't get it. I have an ugly solution which uses SUMPRODUCT, but that requires substituting all the "complete" with 1's (which I'd rather not) + some more. I prefer a Google Sheets solution, but excel would work as well...

Have a heart and help out a teacher :-)

[image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using mmult, which is a standard way of getting row totals from a matrix. As you mention, the first step is to convert each cell containing "complete" into a 1, then check the headers for presence of letter H.

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult((A2:D6="complete")*(isnumber(SEARCH("h",A1:D1))),transpose(column(A2:D6))^0))
```

[image]

I have tested this in Google Sheets, but it should work in Excel as well.

**EDIT**

(1) The easiest way to make the range accommodate changes is to put some upper limit on number of columns and make the references full-column, e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",mmult((A2:M="complete")*(isnumber(SEARCH("h",A1:M1))),transpose(column(A2:M))^0)))
```

You might want to move the total off onto another sheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(Sheet7!A2:A="","",mmult((Sheet7!A2:Z="complete")*(isnumber(SEARCH("h",Sheet7!A1:Z1))),transpose(column(Sheet7!A2:Z))^0)))
```

(2) To get the values as percentages, you can use countif:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(Sheet7!A2:A="","",mmult((Sheet7!A2:Z="complete")*(isnumber(SEARCH("h",Sheet7!A1:Z1))),transpose(column(Sheet7!A2:Z))^0)/countif(Sheet7!A1:Z1,"*h*")))
```

and format column as percent.

**EDIT 2**

To check for presence of H in headers but ignore h, use Find instead of Search, and regexmatch instead of countif:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(Sheet7!A2:A="","",mmult((Sheet7!A2:Z="complete")*(isnumber(find("H",Sheet7!A1:Z1))),transpose(column(Sheet7!A2:Z))^0)/sum(--regexmatch(""&Sheet7!A1:Z1,"H"))))
```

If you only want to include headers _starting_with H, change "H" in the regexmatch to "^H" as in @player0's answer.

Comment: Bingo, Tom! works like a charm. To complete this, could you help with the following? 1. The number of students, i.e. rows is more or less fixed, but the number of exercises grows. Is there a way to automatically detect the bottom right (D6 in your example) and top right (D1), so I don't need to manually change this each time?   2. I'd actually like the "Counts" column to be a percentage, i.e. show  "complete"*H / total H (e.g. for row 2 it would be 100, and for row 4 it would be 50). Keep in mind that the # of exercises keeps growing. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, you could either use a range which which has more rows/columns than you are ever likely to need, or make the ranges indirect. Will have a look later.

Comment: Great! your fix for #1 works (I just plugged it into a column beyond M). For some reason, the other sheet (which is of course cleaner and better) didn't work. My data is indeed stored in Sheet7, and in the calculation tab I copied what you posted but got - "MMULT has incompatible matrix sizes. Number of columns in first matrix (24) must equal number of rows in second matrix (26)." Again, thanks for all the help here!!!

Comment: I actually had the same thing initially when I tried it - at some point I had deleted a column on Sheet7 and the columns only went up to Y. Coincidence that you were on Sheet7 as well though!

Comment: fantastic, thanks so much! OK, all's working now, ready to go for next year. BTW, currently, the 'H' search is not case sensitive. This means that the name of the exercise (currently just 1,2,3 but will be actual names) cannot include an h or will be counted as homework. How do I fix this?

Comment: works, out of the box. OK, that *really* nails it. Thanks again Tom (and Player0) - highly appreciate your help, and greetings from Israel :-)

Answer (score 1):

if position of **`H`** columns is known, you can do simple:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,ADD(D2:D="complete", E2:E="complete")))
```

[image]

---

if the number of columns and position of H's is unknown:

```
=INDEX(MMULT((INDIRECT("A2:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA($A:$A), COLUMN()-1))="complete")
  *(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()-1))), "^H.*")), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:"&COLUMN()-1))^0))
```

[image]

**update**:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(MMULT((INDIRECT("A2:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA($A:$A), COLUMN()-1))="complete")
  *(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()-1))), "^H.*")), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:"&COLUMN()-1))^0)/
 SUM(1*REGEXMATCH(UPPER(INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()-1))), "^H.*")), "0.00%"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you player0. That's exactly the problem - I don't know the position of the H's ahead of time (BTW, this is because I decide in realtime what exercises will be given as homework), plus - the list grows all the time. Any idea?

Comment: thank you very very much for this, player0! appreciate it!!!